# Variable within scala template in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to be able to declare variables and after some markup later I 
need to reference them. In order to accomplish this, this is 
simplified version of my scala template:

```
@(map1: 
java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,Object]]) 
@import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ 
@import play.Logger 
@for( (key,value) <- map1) { 
    <div> 
    @{ 
       val rmap = Foo.someMethod(value) 
       val baz = rmap.getOrElse("baz", null) 
    <table border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  > 
    <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td rowspan="3"> 
        <div class="bar"> 
          @baz 
        </div> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
  } 
  </div> 
}
```

Is above valid scala template and if not how can I declare baz and 
reference it later in the markup? 
I am using 1.2.2RC2 and scala 0.9.1

Comment: Not an answer but a tip: check in tmp/, the scala code generated from your template lives there (in a subdirectory - I don't have a Scala project handy to check). Often helpful to see what exactly happens under the hood :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was curious so did some digging. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Mo8hl5I0tBQ - there is no way at the moment, but an interesting work-around is shown. Define utils/Let.scala:

```
package utils
Object Let {
    def let[A,B](a:A)(f:A=>B):B = f(a)
}
```

and then

```
@import utils.Let._

@let(2+3){ answer =>
   @answer <hr> @answer
}
```

It's a very functional way of handling it, but then, what'd you expect in Scala :)

Comment: Maybe it is newer than this answer, but there's now a "defining" function in Play which does exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a for comprehension:

```
@for( (key,value) <- map1;
     rmap = Foo.someMethod(value);
     baz = rmap.getOrElse("baz", null)
) { 
<div> 
  <table border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  > 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td rowspan="3"> 
          <div class="bar"> 
            @baz 
          </div> 
        </td> 
      </tr> 
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
</div> 
}
```

... and if you don't have anything you need to loop over, you can just say `@for(i <- List(1); <declare variables>){<html here>}`